# Robocopy ignores files that exist in destination subfolders

Tags: windows, robocopy

I am currently using Robocopy to maintain files in two locations. I want to be able to have a subfolder within the destination folder for "completed" files. My problem is while Robocopy continues to run, it will not check to see if the files exist within that subfolder, so I end up with duplicate files.

From what I understand /E will only check subfolders in the source but not the destination.

Is there any way to solve this?

Current program: ROBOCOPY source destination /MOT:1

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear, please explain more what goes on with "completed".

Comment: It's just files that I have finished looking at, excel documents mostly. Once I have finished with the file I want to put them into a subfolder within the destination folder. The problem is that once they are moved to that subfolder Robocopy will copy them again into the destination folder. My hope is for Robocopy to also check that subfolder to see if the file exists in there before copying. Thanks!

Comment: I understand that the problem is in "completed" being copied to the "completed" folder in the target. Question: Are the files moved or copied into "completed", and do the files in "completed" have the same timestamp and size as their counterparts in the target?

Comment: Moved not copied. I want the files to be copied into the destination folder then when I complete them I will move them into the subfolder. Same size and timestamps

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want robocopy to sync source and destination,
and you want to move some files on target to a subfolder, but don't want robocopy
to immediately copy them again from source to target.

Files that are in source but not in the target are called "Lonely".
Therefore, excluding Lonely will prevent any such files from being added
to the destination.

Excluding Lonely is specified by adding the parameter `/xl`.

But be warned that adding this parameter will mean that any genuinely new
file that you start in the source will then need to be manually copied
to the target to benefit from the sync, since it will also be taken as being Lonely.

You could also do the operation of moving the files to "completed"
in the source, and include "completed" in the scan by using the
parameter `/xf completed`.

As a remark, the parameter `/MOT:1` will cause the scanning of both folders
every minute, which might slow your computer when doing other operations.